# Is there a better (Pythonic) or Django way of doing using a table with slight differences across multiple pages?

Tags: python, django, pandas

I'm currently using pandas to create a table which contains prices/data that is a multiple of the 'base' price. for e.g desired function

```
Table I (on page1.html)
.---.-----------.-----------.------------.
|   |     A     |     B     |     C      |
:---+-----------+-----------+------------:
| 1 | $30       | $60       | $90        |
:---+-----------+-----------+------------:
| 2 | =A * 1.25 | =B * 1.25 | =C * 1.125 |
:---+-----------+-----------+------------:
| 3 | =A * 1.5  | =B * 1.5  | =C * 1.5   |
'---'-----------'-----------'------------'

Table II (on pagetwo.html)
.---.-----------.-----------.------------.
|   |     A     |     B     |     C      |
:---+-----------+-----------+------------:
| 1 | $35       | $65       | $95        |
:---+-----------+-----------+------------:
| 2 | =A * 1.25 | =B * 1.25 | =C * 1.125 |
:---+-----------+-----------+------------:
| 3 | =A * 1.5  | =B * 1.5  | =C * 1.5   |
'---'-----------'-----------'------------'
```

there are around 20-30 different tables with different base or row 1 prices/amounts.

Is there a pythonic or django way of using a base template and only having to enter the initial prices in each html page?

I can only think of using a pandas table in a base template without row 1 (initial price) and pass each pages respected row 1 (prices) which then should render?!

Comment: You can create a `jinja2` template and render it with new values everytime.

Comment: Jinja is a framework Django uses no?

Comment: Mate Jinja logic is used in Django?! What are you explicitly getting at? Is there an explicit Jinja feature you're referring to?!

When I said  using a 'base template' in my question - I would obviously {% include.. this in the html.

Comment: I'm asking if there is another 'better' method. A more Pythonic or Django method to achieve what I'm doing. In my case I have to pass all the variables through each page essentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

In `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

MULTIPLES = [1, 1.25, 1.5]

def calculate_rows(prices):
    rows = []
    for mult in MULTIPLES:
        rows.append(
            [mult * price for price in prices]
        )
    return records

def page1(request):
    rows = calculate_rows([30, 60, 90])
    return render(request, 'table.html', {'rows': rows})

def page2(request):
    rows = calculate_rows([35, 65, 95])
    return render(request, 'table.html', {'rows': rows})
```

In `table.html`:

```
<table>
  {% for row in rows %}
    <tr>
      {% for price in row %}
        <td>
          {{price}}
        </td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Yep I though of something like this but how about using Pandas Dataframe as the base template for the table and passing a variable held in the html file that the dataframe would then use. I need to look at Django runtime and see what is parsed first (probably the {% include table %} and datarame are  first which would cause issues. Thank you for your answer =)

Comment: I ended up using this logic but iterating over a dictionary instead. thanks for your help btw the arg in calc_rows() has to be one object (list). I'm sure you know this just for anyone who might read it